# how to perform operations between sheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

My question is very easy and I'm sure there is already an answer somewhere but I don't know the correct keywords when searching for them.

So here is the question:

In column C of sheet2 I want to write the product of two cells from sheet1.

In order to do this I write in cell C2 of sheet2 "=Sheet1!A2*Sheet2!B2".

But now I want to do the same operation for all the elements in the columns A2 and B2. Usually one clicks the black cross at the edge of the cell but this doesn't work when working from one sheet to the other.

I'm using Excel 2011 for the Mac but I guess it is a common issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "but this doesn't work when working from one sheet to the other"? Why can't you fill down the formula on Sheet 2?

Comment: I don't know! I click on the black cross and nothing happens. So I have to click and drag down the column.

Comment: Well, I think the references to other sheets is most likely irrelevant to the problem. It might be better to focus your question on why sometimes double-clicking the corner square fails to fill the formula down the column.

Comment: When you say "One clicks the black cross", were you saying one needs to click the black cross and drag it down to pull the formula down the rows.  Or did you mean one needs to double-click it will copy the formula down the rows. Merely clicking it does nothing ever.

Comment: Double-clicking with the black ✚ (cross) on the black ■ (square) extends the current column to the height (depth? length?) of the highest (tallest/deepest/longest) ***adjoining*** column. You cannot get it to match the height of columns on Sheet1 when you are on Sheet2, unless you already have a column on Sheet2 that is that high.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help!
@G-Man so this means that the only way to extend the vertical height of a column while working between two sheets is to drag it down? Is there another way to do it automatically?

Comment: Well, there's probably some VBA alternative, and (as I indicated) once you've got one column on Sheet2 extended as you like, you can start extending the adjacent ones to match. And, if column `Sheet1!C` is going to match `A` and `B` in height, you may be able to do something tricky like extending columns `Sheet1!C` and `Sheet2!C` simultaneously by selecting `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` simultaneously (click on the tab for `Sheet1`, then Shift-click on the tab for `Sheet2`). But basically, yes; the easiest way to extend the first column on a new sheet is probably to do it manually.

Comment: Probably Excel wants to force us to copy the columns we are using in the new sheet every time. Thanks again!